# Trying to create pull request in Atlassian Bitbucket using REST API in Python

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, bitbucket-server

I am trying to automate the creation of a pull request using a Python script using the requests module.

I can make the request via curl on Linux and it works

```
curl -u devops:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"title":"Test pull request","description":"Description Here","state":"OPEN","open":true,"closed":false,"fromRef":{"id":"refs/heads/feature","repository":{"slug":"joe","name":null,"project":{"key":"SAN"}}},"toRef":{"id":"refs/heads/master","repository":{"slug":"joe","name":null,"project":{"key":"SAN"}}},"locked":false,"reviewers":[{"user":{"name":"jmsmith"}}]}' http://stashdev.blah.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/SAN/repos/joe/pull-requests
```

When I try do exactly the same via the Requests module in python it does not work

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = 'http://stashdev.blah.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/SAN/repos/joe/pull-requests'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
json_data = '{"title":"Test pull request","description":"Description Here","state":"OPEN","open":true,"closed":false,"fromRef":{"id":"refs/heads/feature","repository":{"slug":"joe","name":null,"project":{"key":"SAN"}}},"toRef":{"id":"refs/heads/master","repository":{"slug":"joe","name":null,"project":{"key":"SAN"}}},"locked":false,"reviewers":[{"user":{"name":"jmsmith"}}]}'

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json_data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('devops', 'password'))
```

The json returned is:

```
{u'errors': [{u'message': u'Can not instantiate value of type [map type; class com.atlassian.bitbucket.rest.pull.RestPullRequest, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method', u'exceptionName': u'org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException', u'context': None}]}
```

Can anyone help me understand what is happening here and why this is not working please?

Comment: You've missed a quote in `"Test pull request`. Also your `json_data` should be a dict, and you don't need headers.

Comment: Thanks.  The missing quote was a cut and paste issue.  My real issue was not using a dictionary object.  Have removed the headers too and works without as you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your json data was invalid. You need to post a dictionary object and not string when using 'json' parameter in requests.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = 'http://stashdev.blah.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/SAN/repos/joe/pull-requests'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

json_data = {
    "title":"Test pull request",
    "description":"Description Here",
    "state":"OPEN",
    "open":True,
    "closed":False,
    "fromRef":{
        "id":"refs/heads/feature",
        "repository":{
            "slug":"joe",
            "name":None,
            "project":{
                "key":"SAN"
                }
            }
        },
    "toRef":{
        "id":"refs/heads/master",
        "repository":{
            "slug":"joe",
            "name":None,
            "project":{
                "key":"SAN"
                }
            }
        },
    "locked":False,
    "reviewers":[
            {"user":{
                "name":"jmsmith"
            }
        }
    ]
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json_data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('devops', 'password'))
```